# How to establish validation dependency between two viewmodels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I swear to god, that I had seen something like (below) on one of the MSDN Article but I cant find this property attribute documentation anywhere.

```
public class MyViewModel{
   [Required]
  public bool Important {get;set;}

 [ValidationDependsOn("Important")]
  public bool HasVIPAccess {get;set;}

}
```

If you look at the above code (maybe a bad example), I am trying to establish a relationship between the two properties in such a way that validation of HasVIPAccess property depends on the validation of the property called Important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the built in validation attribute that do something like that is `[Compare("OtherProperty")]` which means the property that you put this attribute on must equal `OtherProperty`

ex

```
public class MyViewModel{
   [Required]
  public bool Important {get;set;}

 [Compare("Important")]
  public bool HasVIPAccess {get;set;}

}
```

**Note : Require MVC 3+**

if you wanna other validation attributes you can check [Mvc.ValidationTookit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx)

---

if you want to understand the science behind it

this is new to mvc3 and you can implement your custom attribute like this fairly easy in mvc3

because IsValid now recives a ValidationContext parameter which contains information about the validation that is being performed like the type of the model and metadata associated with it so you can use reflection to get other properties and their value the CompareAttribute made use of this feature

Comment: this is one of the things. I want to do something like A is valid if A and B both are valid. I thought I had seen it somewhere

Answer (score 1):

[FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a custom validation attribute (this enables only server side validation)... Here is a relevant post [Creating New Data Annotation Validation Attributes in MVC](http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/CreatingDataAnnotationValidationAttributes)

However...if you want to get client side unobstrusive validation to work as well, then you need to do some javascript work...here is another post that talks about creating unobtrusive client side validation...[Unobtrusive Client Validation with MVC 3](http://duncanmcintyre.net/programming/mvc3-razor-unobtrusive-jquery)